# Very long list of ".asc" files in R and apply do.call. How to deal with it?

Tags: r, list, large-data

Hope you can help me with this. I am working on a code which allows me to put together very long list of .asc files (they contain 307200 (640*480) pixel with temperature information from a thermal IR camera each of the files). I have developed the code putting together only 5 files. However, when trying to apply the code over the whole file list (e.g. 4000 .asc files more or less) R gets stuck. I have been told I should modify my code using Batch processing or any optimazing code. However I am not an expert on this field and I need some help.
I have included here the first part of the code which lists all the .asc files and put them together in a sigle dataframe.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.asc")
myfiles = do.call("cbind", lapply(temp, function(x) read.csv(x,
                  sep="\t",dec=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=FALSE)))
mf<-myfiles[c(-1:-8),]

colnames(mf)<-seq(1,ncol(mf),by=1)
rownames(mf)<-seq(1,nrow(mf),by=1)

for (i in 1:ncol(mf)){
      mf[,i]<-sub(",",".",mf[,i])
      mf[,i]<-sub("\t","",mf[,i])
      }

for(i in 1:ncol(mf)){
      mf[,i]<-as.numeric(mf[,i])
      }
```

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Amaia

Comment: At what point does it get stuck? In the second line because you use too much memory?

Comment: Profile your code to identify the bottleneck. One problem are your `for` loops. You should avoid them. E.g., I don't know what the first `for` loop is even doing there. You've specified the correct character for the decimal point when reading the files and the correct column separator. Why are you using `sub` to substitute something that shouldn't exist in your data? And if you don't run the first `for` loop, which turns every numeric variable into a character variable, you won't need the second `for` loop.

Comment: Also, your `for` loops, if you need them at all, can probably be avoided if you replace them with something along the following lines: `mf[] <- lapply(mf, function(x) gsub(",", ".", x)`.

Comment: Do you need to read all the files together? Can't you analyse one file at the time?

Comment: Davi H : yes, it gets stuck because it use a lot of memory,about 8 G. I have been suggested to improve my code by doing some paralelization or batch processing. But i am not experienced on that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Roland: the for loops I include them because I had troubles with my values in the dataframe. I had for coma and decimals "," symbol. I wanted to use "."  for decimals and "" instead of "\t". Somehow the format of the data I exported from the IR camera was a bit messy.

Comment: Nicola: yes I need to put all of them together because I need to do the average of all the files. Each .asc files is one stimestep.